# when move to second fragment the first fragment is showing

Tags: java, android, fragment

when move to second fragment the first fragment is showing!!

i want the first fragment not show in second fragment

my code :

```
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment imageFragment = new Main2Activity();
            ft.replace(R.id.fg_home, imageFragment);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
```

Show : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8ejK.jpg)

Comment: are your using show two fragments at same time

Comment: yes and i want just show second fragment

Comment: how to move one fragment to another fragment like click button or click text?? explain it clearly

Comment: by click on textView

Comment: ok check my ans and let me know i this working or not?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "*first fragment is showing*"? Remove `ft.addToBackStack(null)` if you don't want to nav back to first fragment.

Meanwhile, make sure your `Main2Activity` fragment has a non-transparent background. Otherwise, you can click through it.

Comment: i want move from a fragment to another fragment

Comment: i use a textview  and click on this , but when click on it the first fragment is not disable

Comment: In your Activity.onCreate(Intent), replace R.id.fg_home with your FirstFragment. Set OnClickListener to the textview to replace R.id.fg_home with your SecondFragment and do NOT call addToBackstack.The FirstFragment should then be removed from stack. Make sure the root view in your fragments' layout has a background.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Activity class :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_root__functionality);
        selectedFragment = null;
        selectedFragment = CallLogsClass.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.rootLayout, selectedFragment);
        transaction.commit();
         }
```

use above the code

> 1.initially shown first fragment in your activity.
>
> 2.next go to firstFragment class :
>
> ```
>           1.inside onCreateView() write code to text click event and then move to Second fragment.
> ```